# How to create a count of values in mysql grouped by date?

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a table called `users` with columns `infected` (0 || 1 || NULL) and `date_checkin` (mysql timestamp), `absence` (0 || 1 || NULL).

I want to create a statistic, where I can see, how many guests have the `infected` value 0, 1 or Zero, same for `absence` grouped by the date.

Currently I have the amount of guests:

```
select count(`id`), date(`date_checkin`) as day
from `users` 
group by day
```

I want my result to look like

```
| all | infected | not infected | not tested | absence | not absence |     day    |
|  10 |    5     |       2      |     1      |    2    |      0      | 2021-05-26 |
| ....
```

- infected 1 = infected
- infected 0 = not infected
- infected NULL = not tested
- absense 1 = absence
- absence 0 = not absence
- absence NULL = this value does not matter

Here is some sample data:

```
|  id  |  date_checkin         | inf.  |  abs.    |
---------------------------------------------------
|  42  |  2021-05-04 23:20:11  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  43  |  2021-05-04 23:20:14  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  44  |  2021-05-04 23:20:18  |  NULL |   1      |
|  45  |  2021-05-04 23:20:21  |  NULL |   1      |
|  46  |  2021-05-04 23:20:24  |  1    |   NULL   |
|  47  |  2021-05-04 23:20:28  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  48  |  2021-05-04 23:20:31  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  49  |  2021-05-04 23:20:34  |  1    |   NULL   |
|  50  |  2021-05-05 07:55:15  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  51  |  2021-05-05 11:56:41  |  NULL |   1      |
|  52  |  2021-05-05 12:55:12  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  53  |  2021-05-09 11:13:12  |  NULL |   1      |
|  54  |  2021-05-17 17:33:52  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  55  |  2021-05-17 17:34:42  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  56  |  2021-05-18 11:12:31  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  57  |  2021-05-18 15:09:36  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  58  |  2021-05-18 15:20:59  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  59  |  2021-05-18 15:21:16  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  62  |  2021-05-18 15:25:40  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  63  |  2021-05-18 15:29:33  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  64  |  2021-05-18 16:02:02  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  65  |  2021-05-18 16:07:33  |  1    |   NULL   |
|  66  |  2021-05-18 16:07:51  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  67  |  2021-05-18 16:09:28  |  NULL |   1      |
|  68  |  2021-05-18 16:12:12  |  NULL |   1      |
|  69  |  2021-05-18 16:12:31  |  NULL |   1      |
|  70  |  2021-05-18 16:12:54  |  NULL |   1      |
|  71  |  2021-05-18 16:22:03  |  NULL |   1      |
|  72  |  2021-05-18 16:22:26  |  NULL |   1      |
|  73  |  2021-05-19 11:04:27  |  NULL |   1      |
|  79  |  2021-05-19 12:27:31  |  NULL |   1      |
|  80  |  2021-05-21 14:28:19  |  NULL |   1      |
|  81  |  2021-05-21 14:28:30  |  NULL |   1      |
|  82  |  2021-05-21 14:34:39  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  83  |  2021-05-21 14:35:47  |  NULL |   1      |
|  84  |  2021-05-21 14:36:54  |  NULL |   1      |
|  85  |  2021-05-21 14:38:26  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  86  |  2021-05-21 14:39:38  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  87  |  2021-05-21 14:39:39  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  88  |  2021-05-21 14:39:39  |  0    |   NULL   |
|  89  |  2021-05-21 14:39:42  |  0    |   NULL   |
```

Comment: This is known as a [tag:pivot].

Comment: Please add sample input table data to your question, along with the exact output you want to see.  You want some kind of pivot query, but the previous duplicate link is probably not close enough to the answer to this question.

Comment: I added sample data to my quesiton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(`id`) AS counts,
    SUM(CASE WHEN infected = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS infected,
    SUM(CASE WHEN infected = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS not_infected, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN infected IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS not_tested,
    SUM(CASE WHEN absence = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS absence,
    SUM(CASE WHEN absence = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS not_absence,
    DATE(`date_checkin`) AS selected_day
FROM 
    users
GROUP BY 
    selected_day;
```

Comment: You are treating the `1` and `0` as string. These are `tinyint` values (I did not mention that in my question). As they are no strings, will the SUM part change a little bit? It is working as it is but `IF 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0` is redundant.